# project references are "lost" after getting latest from TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I have a solution with many projects.  This is actually a solution that contains a mix of class libraries and various web applications.  It seems that if my colleague makes a change to one of the web projects (or if I do) and then check it in.  And then when either one of us gets the latest version project references become broken.  They still appear in the references section with no indication of an error, but when you try to compile it cannot see the libraries.

To solve this I have to remove the references and add them back in.  Any ideas on what may cause this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the paths are relocatable, that you both have the same paths on your PCs (i.e. that you have not used TFS workspace mappings to put different folders in different places), and that you don't move projects around or rename folders etc.

Even when everything is clean and tidy, Visual Studio will occasionally decide it can't find a file that's right under its nose, or that a file somewhere else on your system looks prettier, and it will break the reference. You just have to delete and recreate it in this case. But this usually happens once a month in a team of 10-20 people, and should not occur every time you check in.